# How to create dynamic methods with python?

Tags: python, django

For my project I need to dynamically create custom (Class) methods.

I found out it is not so easy in Python:

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    '''
    This filter is used in the API
    '''
    # legacy below, this has to be added dynamically
    #is_field_type1 = MethodFilter(action='filter_field_type1') 

    #def filter_field_type1(self, queryset, value):
    #    return queryset.filter(related_field__field_type1=value)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = []
```

But it is giving me errors (and headaches...). Is this even possible?

I try to make the code between #legacy dynamic

One option to do this I found was to create the class dynamically

```
def create_filter_dict():
    new_dict = {}
    for field in list_of_fields:

        def func(queryset, value):
            _filter = {'stableuser__'+field:value}
            return queryset.filter(**_filter)

        new_dict.update({'filter_'+field: func})

        new_dict.update({'is_'+field: MethodFilter(action='filter_'+field)})

    return new_dict


meta_model_dict = {'model': get_user_model(), 'fields':[]}
meta_type = type('Meta',(), meta_model_dict)

filter_dict = create_filter_dict()
filter_dict['Meta'] = meta_type
UserFilter = type('UserFilter', (django_filters.FilterSet,), filter_dict)
```

However, this is giving me

```
TypeError at /api/v2/users/
func() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Does anyone know how to solve this dilemma?

Comment: "this does not work" is probably just about the worst way you could possibly give a diagnosis of your issue

Comment: That's not how you create a classmethod. What are you even trying to do here? You have a class definition inside another class definition (which is totally possible, just surely not what you want)... wha problem are you even trying to solve?

Comment: show the complete traceback

Comment: @joelgoldstick i suspect the traceback will not be super helpful as it is just entirely unclear what the OP is asking for here

Comment: point taken, but a good habit when asking

Comment: I try to make the code between #legacy dynamic, because if have about 7 (and growing) fields for which I want to have this filter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is just totally the wrong way to go about it. Just make **one simple function** (method) that implements your filter, and call it at the beginning of every method that uses it. Problem solved.

Comment: You are right, but this is the first time I use @classmehod and I even don't know if I need it here to make it work. I have looked everywhere, but they only use setattr to set a function that does not take an argument, while I need two arguments.

Comment: Maybe I should just override the MethodFilter itself?

Comment: All `@classmethod` does is make it where (1.) the first argument is a reference to the class, not an instance of the class, and (2.) You call the function directly from the class, not (necessarily) an instance of the class. I'm not sure why you're using it either, tbh.

Comment: @WayneWerner: I'm pretty sure sticking a `class Meta` inside another class is a normal thing to do in Django. I don't know *what* it does, having no experience with Django, but it's in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#meta-options).

Comment: Trying to change the `FilterSet` class in `__init__()` is already much too late. At that point, [`FilterSetMetaclass`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/a21dc78fee0d8c7bef093ea20633d7c11e8859f5/django_filters/filterset.py#L146) has already done all the relevant setup. You need to either build the `FilterSet` class dynamically (`type()`) or dig into django-filter and find a better way.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah. It looks like Django will look for a `Meta` class inside your class, and it's really just a container for non-field data. But, uh, it also looks like that should be for models and not filters? Or are filters also models?

Comment: @WayneWerner: The `FilterSet` seems to be coming from [django-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter), which seems to have a similar `class Meta` API.

Comment: The error you're getting in EDIT 3 is because `dict.update` returns `None`, not the `dict`.

Comment: Might help to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360368/lambda-function-for-classes-in-python

Comment: The question could use some clean up to remove non-relevant, old code and errors.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception Value: 'UserFilter' object has no attribute 'is_bound'

You are getting this error because the class methods you are generating, are not bound to any class. To bound them to the class, you need to use setattr()

Try this on a console:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

@classmethod 
def unbound(cls):
    print "Now I'm bound to ", cls


print unbound
setattr(MyClass, "bound", unbound) 
print MyClass.bound 
print MyClass.bound()
```

> Traceback:
>       UserFilter = type('Foo', (django_filters.FilterSet, ), create_filter_dict().update({'Meta':type('Meta',(), {'model':
>   get_user_model(), 'fields':[]} )})) TypeError: type() argument 3 must
>   be dict, not None

Now, this is failing because dict.update() doesn't return the same instance, returns None. That can be fixed easily

```
class_dict = create_filter_dict()
class_dict.update({'Meta':type('Meta',(), {'model': get_user_model(), 'fields':[]})}
UserFilter = type('Foo', (django_filters.FilterSet, ), class_dict))
```

However, just look how messy that code looks. I recommend to you to try to be
clearer with the code you write even if it requires to write a few extra lines. In the long run, the code will be easier to maintain for you and your team.

```
meta_model_dict = {'model': get_user_model(), 'fields':[]}
meta_type = type('Meta',(), meta_model_dict)

filter_dict = create_filter_dict()
filter_dict['Meta'] = meta_type
UserFilter = type('Foo', (django_filters.FilterSet,), filter_dict)
```

This code might not be perfect but it is more readable than the original line of code you posted:

```
UserFilter = type('Foo', (django_filters.FilterSet, ), create_filter_dict().update({'Meta':type('Meta',(), {'model': get_user_model(), 'fields':[]})}))
```

And removes a complication on an already kinda difficult concept to grasp.

You might want to learn about metaclasses. Maybe you can overwrite the **new** method of a class. I can recommend you [1](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) or [2](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example) posts about that.

Another option is that maybe you are not adding the filters correctly or in a way django doesn't expect? That would explain why you get no errors but none of your functions gets called.

Comment: Wow, I really learned something today and although I did not check the answer yet, this is really going to help me build it! Also the references you mention about metaclass are great! Bounty well spent :)

Comment: Okay, it does not work yet. Still trying, so any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to add a simple filter that works well maybe for just one case?
Try to see what it's making that work, and what you might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod). Here is example how you can use it:

```
class UserFilter:
    @classmethod
    def filter_field(cls, queryset, value, field = None):
        # do somthing
        return "{0} ==> {1} {2}".format(field, queryset, value)
    @classmethod
    def init(cls,list_of_fields ):
        for field in list_of_fields:
            ff = lambda cls, queryset, value, field=field: cls.filter_field(queryset, value, field )
            setattr(cls, 'filter_'+field, classmethod( ff ))

UserFilter.init( ['a','b'] )
print(UserFilter.filter_a(1,2)) # a ==> 1 2
print(UserFilter.filter_b(3,4)) # b ==> 3 4
```

Comment: It does not give me any errors, but is also does not add the filter to the query. I think your code does not play well with django_filters.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for:

> custom (Class) methods.

So we take an existing class and derive a subclass where you can add new methods or overwrite the methods of the original existing class (look into the code of the original class for the methods you need) like this:

```
from universe import World
class NewEarth(World.Earth):
   def newDirectionUpsideDown(self,direction):
       self.rotationDirection = direction
```

All the other Methods and features of World.Earth apply to NewEarth only you can now change the direction to make the world turn your new way.

To overwrite an existing method of a class is as as easy as this.

```
class NewEarth(World.Earth):
   def leIitRain(self,amount): # let's assume leIitRain() is a standard-function of our world
       return self.asteroidStorm(amount) #let's assume this is possible Method of World.Earth
```

So if someone likes a cool shower on earth he/she/it or whatever makes room for new development on the toy marble the burning way.

So have fun in your way learning python - and don't start with complicated things.

If I got you completely wrong - you might explain your problem in more detail - so more wise people than me can share their wisdom.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a custom *dynamiccally generated* class method. So your example of inheritance is not going to answer the question.

Comment: If I search on http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html nothing states that you should use dynamic classes or dynamic functions/methods. MAYBE the word "dynamically" in the comments is misleading?